# How to print an int sequence in blocks of 5 in Java

Tags: java

I’m stuck with a Java exercise and I'd really appreciate some guidance.

I have to input two numbers (the first one between 100 and 150, and the second one between 10 and 50) and print out the numbers in between, in a new line every five numbers.

E.g. If I input 130 and 49, I need to print out:

129 128 127 126 125

124 123 122 121 120

119 ...

I've been able to do the number validation and show the numbers between them in a single line, but I can't figure out how to build the line breaks every five numbers.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Input number”);

int num=keyboard.nextInt();

while(num<100 || num>150) {
        System.out.println(“Input number between 100 and 150");
        num=keyboard.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println(“Input number 2”);
    int num2=keyboard.nextInt();

while (num2<10 || num2>50){
        System.out.println(“Input number between 10 and 50");
        num2=keyboard.nextInt();
    }

int i = num;

for (i=num;i>=num2;i--) {
       System.out.print(i+" ");
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: It seems you forgot to include a question in your question.

Comment: And you forgot to write a title that actually describes your core issue.

Comment: how about, for example, using a counter variable, incrementing it each time you print a number, and print a new line every time it reaches 5, 10, 15, etc.? Or simply reset it to 0 when it reaches 5?

Comment: Well there is no question mark, but imo it is still quite clear what the question is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just as pietergdp's answer, but use your iteration variable instead

```
int rem = (num + 1) % 5;

for ( i = num; i >= num2 ; i--) {
      System.out.print(i+" ");
      if(i % 5 == rem){
         System.out.print( "\n" ); // this inserts the line break
      }
}
```

Let me explain. 
We don't know wich number the for loop will start at. So using mod 5 isn't gonna insert a line break after the fifth number, but when the number has a remainder of 0. Wich could be at the first number if the loop starts at 100.

So, a workaround, is to add 1 to your initial number (wich would be the fifth number of the previous row if there was one) then you caculate its remainder. Then every time a number has the same remainder you calculated will be the fifth number in that row. Resulting in inserting the line break

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate your explanation. I've been struggling with this exercise for a couple of days and I couldn't figure it out, but finally I can understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using mod, eg.

```
if(countnum % 5 == 0){
    do something
}
```

Comment: That's a tad misleading. Modulo is called for, but not based upon the number being printed, but on _how many_ numbers have been printed.

Answer (score 0):

First you should do:

```
do{
System.out.println(“Input number between 100 and 150");
num=keyboard.nextInt();
}
while(!(num>100 && num<150));
```

intead of:

```
while(num<100 || num>150) {
        System.out.println(“Input number between 100 and 150");
        num=keyboard.nextInt();
    }
```

similar for the second check:

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion, @ScottS

Comment: No problem.  :) Anytime.

Answer (score 0):

In order to print out your numbers in the format you listed above with the numbers in groups of 5 you need to add the following to your for loop.

```
int outputCount = 0;
    for (i=num;i>=num2;i--) {
        System.out.print(i+" ");
        if(outputCount%5==4)
        {
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
        outputCount++;
    }
```

That should make it print properly.  This works by taking advantage of the mod operator.  Every time you are at the 5th number in the output on the line the remainder of the index number divided by 5 will be 4.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It makes perfect sense, I'll give it a try

Comment: @Neypu: this only works when `num%5==0`, i.e is divisible by 5. For 150 ir works, but for 149 it does not.

Comment: @user140547 This should handle every case now.  It looks at the output rather than the number.

Comment: @Neypu If you try it again, it should work for all cases now.

Comment: Thanks again @davloi. Every case works just fine now

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use mod, but it is not a simple mod operation.

```
int offset = num % 5; // calculate the offset of the first number
for (i = num; i >= num2; i--) {
    if (i % 5 == offset && i!=num) { 
    // every five lines, but not at the beginning, print a new line
        System.out.println("");
    }
    System.out.print(i + " ");
}
```

You could also use a second counter variable, so you don't have to deal with the offset:

```
for (int i = num, j = 0; i >= num2; i--, j++) {
    if (j % 5 == 0 && j > 0) System.out.println("");
    System.out.print(i + " ");
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Using a second variable looks even cleaner to me.